# WordPress: LinkedIn Posting Link doesn't show meta og description or title

Tags: html, wordpress, linkedin-api, meta-tags, yoast

Does anyone else have this problem or can you see what may be wrong on my end?

**Problem**: If I go to LinkedIn (business or personal) and post a link to one of my websites:

- https://inventivewebdesign.com/
- https://www.revealio.com/

I get the image, but I don't get the title or description. Both sites are using WordPress with the latest version of Yoast SEO. I asked LinkedIn and they just said that my meta og tags need to be added to my site, but when I look at the source code for each page on either site I can see them there. Is there something that I am missing?

This is what LinkedIn Customer support said:

> You'll need to make sure the source code complies with Open Graph
>   Protocol (OGP) and certain image requirements specific to LinkedIn.
>   Our developer website contains more details on setting display tags
>   for shares (available in English only). Below are the og: tags that
>   must exist and their correct format:
>
> ```
> <meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>
> <meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>
> <meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>
> <meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />
> ```
>
> Here are the image requirements specific to the LinkedIn sharing
>   module:
>
> ```
> Max file size: 5 MB
> Minimum image dimensions: 1200 (w) x 627 (h) pixels
> Recommended ratio: 1.91:1
> ```

These are the OG tags on my site:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.revealio.com/features/" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="REVEALiO" />
<meta property="og:title" content="How To Make Your Message Come Alive With REVEALiO" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="How To Make Your Message Come Alive With REVEALiO" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.revealio.com/wp-content/uploads/BC_phone_scan-iPhone-wText-1.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://www.revealio.com/wp-content/uploads/BC_phone_scan-iPhone-wText-1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="REVEALiO Is a Video Marketing Technology That Makes Your Promotional Materials COME ALIVE With A Personal Video Message and Call To Action Buttons" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="REVEALiO Is a Video Marketing Technology That Makes Your Promotional Materials COME ALIVE With A Personal Video Message and Call To Action Buttons" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@Revealiocards" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Revealiocards" />
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Test your page(s) on [LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/). I can see your correct meta info with the other ones, but not sure why they are not using the correct one.

Comment: Can you test the page(s) without minifcation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not having any trouble with your `title` tag, but your `description` tag is definitely missing.  LinkedIn provides two levels, which each are triggered in their own way, but they are mutually exclusive...

- **Level 1**

  - *If you supply:* `og:image` tags.
  - *The preview shows:* title, url, image.
- **Level 2**

  - *If you supply:* no `og:image` tags, but an `og:description` tag.
  - *The preview shows:* title, url, description.

Your site is using level 1...

[image]

[**The Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share Documentation**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en) makes no mention of these levels.  But I have been informed by [LinkedIn support staff](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-broken-ticket.html) that they exist, and experimentation seems to confirm it.

Example: Wikipedia has `og:description` and is missing `og:image`, so, [sharing Wikipedia](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.org%2F) shows the description.  But GitHub has both `og:description` and `og:image`, so, [sharing GitHub](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.github.com%2F) shows the image.